# How to use a variable for the database name in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I use the database name in several places in my script, and I want to be able to quickly change it, so I'm looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(50)
SET @DBNAME = 'TEST'

CREATE DATABASE @DBNAME
GO
ALTER DATABASE @DBNAME SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
GO
ALTER DATABASE @DBNAME SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
```

But it doesn't work. So what's the correct way to write this code?

Comment: Strongly related: [How can I do something like: USE @databaseName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3788566/1364007)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Put the entire script into a template string, with {SERVERNAME} placeholders. Then edit the string using:

```
SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@TEMPLATE, '{SERVERNAME}', @DBNAME)
```

and then run it with

```
EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT)
```

---

It's hard to believe that, in the course of three years, nobody noticed that my code **doesn't work**!

You can't `EXEC` multiple batches. `GO` is a batch separator, not a T-SQL statement. It's necessary to build three separate strings, and then to `EXEC` each one after substitution.

I suppose one could do something "clever" by breaking the single template string into multiple rows by splitting on `GO`; I've done that in ADO.NET code.

And where did I get the word "SERVERNAME" from?

Here's some code that I just tested (and which works):

```
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(255)
SET @DBNAME = 'TestDB'

DECLARE @CREATE_TEMPLATE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COMPAT_TEMPLATE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RECOVERY_TEMPLATE VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @CREATE_TEMPLATE = 'CREATE DATABASE {DBNAME}'
SET @COMPAT_TEMPLATE='ALTER DATABASE {DBNAME} SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90'
SET @RECOVERY_TEMPLATE='ALTER DATABASE {DBNAME} SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'

DECLARE @SQL_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@CREATE_TEMPLATE, '{DBNAME}', @DBNAME)
EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT)

SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@COMPAT_TEMPLATE, '{DBNAME}', @DBNAME)
EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT)

SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@RECOVERY_TEMPLATE, '{DBNAME}', @DBNAME)
EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT)
```

Comment: +1 Very nice approach... You just saved me from a ton of work, thx... Though it should be EXECUTE(@SQL_SCRIPT), or at least that is what worked for me.

Comment: Need to be careful with escaping, though.

Comment: `SYSNAME` would be a more appropriate datatype than `VARCHAR(255)` also should use `QUOTENAME` to deal with all possible database names (and possibly to prevent SQL injection depending on source of the name)

Comment: Doesn't work if I want to `CREATE SCHEMA` in other database, using `USE {DBNAME}`. Schema creates in wrong database ;/

Answer (score 110):

You can also use [`sqlcmd`](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/) mode for this (enable this on the "Query" menu in Management Studio).

```
:setvar dbname "TEST" 

CREATE DATABASE $(dbname)
GO
ALTER DATABASE $(dbname) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
GO
ALTER DATABASE $(dbname) SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
```

**EDIT:**

Check this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) article to set parameters via the SQLCMD tool.

Comment: how can this method use already declared variables? Instead of "TEST" can you add a @dbName? I tried and didn't work

Comment: @syclee A TSQL variable? No the sqlcmd substitutions are carried out before the script is even sent to the server.

Comment: @MartinSmith Hey i want the db name as a OUTPUT command. So how can i have it using SQLCMD.?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately you can't declare database names with a variable in that format.

For what you're trying to accomplish, you're going to need to wrap your statements within an EXEC() statement. So you'd have something like:

```
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max) ='CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBNAME
```

Then call

```
EXECUTE(@Sql) or sp_executesql(@Sql)
```

to execute the sql string.

Comment: `EXEC` looks for a stored procedure.  In this case `EXECUTE` is needed.

Comment: Actually I need to apologize.  It turns out `EXEC` and `EXECUTE` are the same.  I made the statement after failing with `EXEC` and succeeding with `EXECUTE`. Though obviously my real problem was unrelated to either.

Comment: Don't do this in production... Ever.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn vary old post and very comments but I am curious know why not? shouldn't it be requirement specific??

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Is that because of potential for injection?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a variable in a create table statement.  The best thing I can suggest is to write the entire query as a string and exec that.

Try something like this:

```
declare @query varchar(max);
set @query = 'create database TEST...';

exec (@query);
```