# Setting database name as a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

currently, I'm doing a bit of a data migration between one db to another based on some business rules.

I have this huge script that I'm writing where I'm referencing both databases a lot of times. The problem is that this data migration is currently in development, at some point I am going to want to have to do it in production with two different databases.

Instead of referencing the database name directly like so

```
Insert Into Database2.dbo.Table1    
Select * from Database1.dbo.Table1
```

I would like to somehow just reference the database at the start of the script. So that I can just change the one variable when I change databases.

Is that possible?

Comment: Only means I know of relies on dynamic SQL.  Otherwise, create one script.  Copy it, and do a replace on the references for the intended source & target database references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variable for database name in t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [SQLCMD variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx):

```
:setvar dbfrom database1
:setvar dbto database2

Insert into [$(dbto)].dbo.Table1
select * from [$(dbfrom)].dbo.Table2;
```

This syntax works in sqlcmd.exe (from scripts), as well as in Management Studio, see [Editing SQLCMD Scripts with Query Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx). Scripting also allows you to set the variables from the command line:

```
sqlcmd /E /S server /i script.sql /v dbfrom=database1 /v dbto=database2
```

I also have a [library that allows you to use sqlcmd variables and scripts from applications](http://code.google.com/p/dbutilsqlcmd/) available as source on Google Code.

Comment: thanks that's good. although the intellisense stops working but i don't think there is a solution that caters for that.