# Using a Database Name as a Variable

Tags: sql, variables, replace, set, exec

I'm using this method ([How to use a variable for the database name in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql/8054127#8054127)) to pass a DBname into a variable. This variable is then used with something like this (simplified):

`Select column From @DBname`

However, when executed...You get, `Command(s) completed successfully`

Is there a way to adapt this method so that you can see the results of a query? (Not just create or alter a DB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.

```
[[put code here that sets up @DBname]]
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT column FROM ' + @DBname;
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @stmt;
```

**Edit:** Note that I'm assuming you're using SQL server (you didn't specify in the question).

Comment: This works. I'm new to SQL - Didn't know about sp_ExecuteSQL. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted so that people can easily see the solution. Thanks.