# TSQL: variable for access to database (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written a T-SQL script that migrates some data from one database to another.
At the moment I am doing that by use of dynamic sql.

For example see the following code:

```
Declare @sqlquery nvarchar(4000)
SET @sqlquery = N'SELECT * from ' + @LinkServerName + @SourceDatabaseName + '.dbo.Table'
EXEC @sqlquery
```

In this example `@LinkServerName` is a `nvarchar` variable that stores the name of the linked server for the SQL Server that contains the source database. `@SourceDatabaseName` is a `nvarchar` variable that stores the name of the source database.

I don´t like that way. I would prefer the following code:

```
SELECT * from @SourceDatabase.dbo.Table
```

Is that possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, that second approach **is not valid T-SQL** since you cannot use variables for column or table names in your T-SQL statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variable for database name in t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach is incorrect, first one is the correct one. For more information check this other question here at stackoverflow [how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql)