# Dynamic use of USE command

Tags: sql, t-sql

In TSQL I frequently use the `use` (excuse me for the wordplay):

```
use choosenOne
```

set the `choosenOne` database as active database.
Suppose now something like:

```
DECLARE @NewDB varchar(255) 
SET @NewDB = 'choosenOne'
```

I want dinamically compose a valid use command, but I have no luck, since these codes aren't working:

```
use @NewDB          -- Incorrect syntax near '@NewDB'.
EXEC('use '+@NewDB) -- No runtime error but no change of db is performed
```

What is the right way?

Comment: A  change of db is actually performed. It just is only valid for the child scope and gets changed back when the scope exits.

Comment: This post provides a detailed solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql

Comment: In addition to the solution in the question that J Tolley linked to, [SQLCMD scripting variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) are intended for exactly this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your query into `EXEC` command after `'use '+@NewDB`:

```
DECLARE @NewDB varchar(255) 
SET @NewDB = 'choosenOne'
EXEC('use '+@NewDB + '
 ...............')
```

Comment: I was looking for a more elegant solution. Too many quotes in the real query and really error prone and unreadable solution in this case.