# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ' '

Tags: sql-server, msg

I wrote the following code:

```
Declare @DaataBaseName2 varchar(50)

set @DaataBaseName2 = 'LUNDB14644A01'  -- @DaataBaseName
USE @DaataBaseName2  --LUNDB14644A01
GO
```

I received following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '@DaataBaseName2'.

Why?

Comment: please provide more information about the language, environment and what you have tried

Comment: Because you **cannot** use a variable in a `USE` command - only literal database names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variable for database name in t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to execute your code via dynamic SQL.  You have to be careful with dynamic sql as it can lead to sql injection attack.

Here is a small scale sample of how to use a dynamic database.

```
Declare @DaataBaseName2 varchar(50),
        @sql nvarchar(Max)
set @DaataBaseName2 = 'master'  -- @DaataBaseName
set @sql = 'USE ' + @DaataBaseName2 + ';' + CHAR(13)
SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT db_name()'

exec sp_executesql @sql
GO
```