# Sqlserver: Variable database name in create database query is throwing error

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
 Use master 
    GO
    Declare @dbName As VARCHAR(50)
    SET @dbName = 'TestDB'
    CREATE DATABASE @dbName
```

Above sqlserver is script is giving me error. Why?

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '@dbName'.
```

Comment: Try this...`Declare @dbName As VARCHAR(50)
 Declare @createdbName As VARCHAR(500)
    SET @dbName = 'TestDB'
select @createdbName ='CREATE DATABASE'+ @dbName
exec (@createdbName)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variable for database name in t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use dynamic sql and ddl as mixed.
Use dynamic sql .
Try this code:

```
Use master 
    GO
    Declare @dbName As VARCHAR(50) 
    DECLARE @Q VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @dbName = 'TestDB'
    SET @Q='CREATE DATABASE '+ @dbName
    EXEC(@Q)
```

Answer (score 0):

If won't work because you're passing a VARCHAR type and for the creation of a database, it takes an object instead of a Varchar. Else, you'll need to pass the whole query as a string to execution;

```
Declare @dbName As VARCHAR(50) = 'TestDB'
DECLARE @Creation VARCHAR(50) ='CREATE DATABASE '+ @dbName 
EXEC(@Creation)
```