# DB name as parameter in user-defined function

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to use DB name as parameter in user-defined function?

For example I've tried to use concatenation but it doesn't work in this way:

```
create function fn_getEntityOwners (@dbName varchar, @entityId bigint)
returns table
as
return 
select
    OWNERS.USER_ID 
from 
    @dbName + '.dbo.OWNERS' as OWNERS
where 
    OWNERS.ENTITY_ID = @entityId
```

UPDATE: I use sql server

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variable for database name in t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql)

Comment: @AndriyM My question is more specific because I need to use DB name as parameter in user-defined function and function imposes some restrictions.

Comment: Well, you just can't parametrise a *name* (DB name, column name, table name). Almost all the answers (both there and here) suggest using dynamic SQL. You can't use dynamic SQL in a function, which means you are getting nowhere with *this particular question*. I would suggest you ask a new question, where you might want to elaborate a little on what you are trying to do, and where you would ask specifically for alternatives to using dynamic SQL (or, perhaps, for alternatives to using a function?).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've added a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164328/filtering-records-by-user-access-rights)

Answer (score 3):

Put your code in function into a string and execute by dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(2000)

SELECT @SQL = 

'select
    OWNERS.USER_ID 
from 
    ' + @dbName + '.dbo.OWNERS as OWNERS
where 
    OWNERS.ENTITY_ID = ' + @entityId


EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Don't like this approach much because query becomes a string and isn't validated by SQL Server Management Studio. But anyway thank you for your solution. Other ideas?

Comment: are you worried about the database not existing and throwing an error? if so can always add code to check if exists before querying for the user_id...IF db_id(@dbName) IS NOT NULL BEGIN...

Comment: No, I'm worried about situation when you make mistake in sql query but because it is just a string you will know this only after function execution. I've shown just a simple example but imagine that query inside function is big and complicated.

Comment: It is not possible to use exec in function

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL to do this.  What DB is this?  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure) another SO question that relates

Comment: Great, SQL Server will support dynamic SQL.

Comment: See my comment to @DominionDave

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sqlcmd` mode for this (*enable this on the "Query" menu in Management Studio*).

```
:setvar dbname "TEST.dbo.OWNERS" 

select
    OWNERS.USER_ID 
from 
    $(dbname) as OWNERS
where 
    OWNERS.ENTITY_ID = @entityId
```

---

... this solution brought to you by [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-variable-for-database-name-in-t-sql) ...

---

> whatup @DominionDave - Nice to have you on SO playa  :-D