# Filtering records by user access rights

Tags: sql-server

I have a legacy system and it works with several databases at the same time. Assume they are MASTER and SLAVE.

There are user groups (hierarchical structure). Each group has one parent group, parent group can have own parent and so on.

```
table MASTER.dbo.GROUPS: 
GROUP_ID
PARENTGROUP_ID
NAME
```

User can be assigned to different groups.

```
table MASTER.dbo.LK_GROUPS:
GROUP_ID
USER_ID
```

There are entities, each entity has owners (one-to-many).

```
table SLAVE.dbo.ENTITY_OWNERSHIP
ENTITY_ID
USER_ID (column has a bad name because it is GROUP_ID)
```

Task:
Write query/function/stored procedure to select only those entities user has access to. It should be possible to use solution as part of sql query which I can't modify. Also it should be possible to use 2 modes:

1. Assuming that owners of entity is S1 set and groups of user is S2 set, entity is accessible if S1 - S2 = 0.
2. Assuming that owners of entity is S1 set and groups of user is S2 set, entity is accessible if S1 intersect S2 > 0.

So I wrote a function fn_checkUserRights:

```
create function fn_checkUserRights (@userId bigint, @entityId bigint, @compareMode int)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @result int;
    declare @count int;

    if @compareMode = 1
        begin

            with groups_with_ancestors
            as (
                select GROUP_ID, PARENTGROUP_ID, NAME
                from MASTER.dbo.GROUPS as GROUPS
                where 
                    GROUP_ID in (
                        select 
                            GROUP_ID
                        from 
                            MASTER.dbo.LK_GROUPS
                        where 
                            USER_ID = @userId
                    )

                union all

                select 
                    b.GROUP_ID, b.PARENTGROUP_ID, b.NAME
                from 
                    groups_with_ancestors a
                    inner join MASTER.dbo.GROUPS b on b.GROUP_ID = a.PARENTGROUP_ID
            ) 
            select @count = count(*) from (
                select
                    ENTITY_OWNERSHIP.USER_ID as OWNER_ID 
                from 
                    SLAVE.dbo.ENTITY_OWNERSHIP as ENTITY_OWNERSHIP
                where 
                    ENTITY_OWNERSHIP.ENTITY_ID = @entityId

                except

                select distinct GROUP_ID from groups_with_ancestors

            ) a

            if @count > 0
                set @result = 0
            else
                set @result = 1
        end

    else if @compareMode = 2
        begin

            with groups_with_ancestors
            as (
                select GROUP_ID, PARENTGROUP_ID, NAME
                from MASTER.dbo.GROUPS as GROUPS
                where GROUP_ID in (
                        select 
                            GROUP_ID
                        from 
                            MASTER.dbo.LK_GROUPS
                        where 
                            USER_ID = @userId
                    )

                union all

                select 
                    b.GROUP_ID, b.PARENTGROUP_ID, b.NAME
                from 
                    groups_with_ancestors a
                    inner join MASTER.dbo.GROUPS b on b.GROUP_ID = a.PARENTGROUP_ID
            ) 
            select @count = count(*) from (
                select
                    ENTITY_OWNERSHIP.USER_ID as OWNER_ID 
                from 
                    SLAVE.dbo.ENTITY_OWNERSHIP as ENTITY_OWNERSHIP
                where 
                    ENTITY_OWNERSHIP.ENTITY_ID = @entityId

                intersect

                select distinct GROUP_ID from groups_with_ancestors

            ) a

            if @count > 0
                set @result = 1
            else
                set @result = 0

        end


    return @result;

end;
```

Example of usage:

```
select * 
from 
    SLAVE.dbo.ENTITY_OWNERSHIP as owners
where 
    MASTER.dbo.fn_checkUserRights(10010, owners.ENTITY_ID, 1) = 1
```

However there are some issues:

1. function uses tables from 2 DBs: MASTER and SLAVE. Theirs names are not known beforehand. I can't pass  names as parameters because functions don't allow dynamic query execution. How to resolve this issue?
2. blocks of code for @compareMode=1 and @compareMode=2 are almost the same and it would be great to extract common code to variables or functions. What can you recommend?

Comment: Wait, where are you going to actually filter records based on user rights?  And how will you pass the current identity of a user to your function?  And if you can't modify queries, how will you ever filter anything?  I'm removing my answer from below as I don't feel like there are enough details in your question.  I suggested a sproc and you said you couldnt use one, but your question clearly has this: `Task: Write query/function/stored procedure to select only those entities...`

Comment: Why not create it as a view in two different schema with users belonging to different schema will see only what it is in their view? This way when use connects they can query the view but only see what you allow them.

Comment: @SaUce As I know it's not possible to pass parameters to the view. Could you write an example for what you mean.

Comment: Create two schema, in each schema create a view with specific where clause, than bind each user to different schema. When user connects to get data from the view, user will be getting data from what is available to him not what it is in the underlying table.