# "Create Database"-SQL with name from variable fails

Tags: sql-server

I used an existing database to generate a "CREATE"-Script via the MS SQL Server Management Tool. Then i replaced the string literals for the DB Name with variables. However, when i execute the script, it keeps saying "wrong syntax near @DBFullName" (the first use in 'NAME = @DBFullName ...'). I have no idea what the issue is, other than the possibility, that the use of variables is forbidden here.

```
DECLARE @DBNAME nvarchar(MAX);
SET @DBNAME = 'MyDataBase'

DECLARE @DBFullName text;
SET @DBFullName = 'MySuperDataBase';

DECLARE @DBFileName text;
SET @DBFileName = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\\' + @DBName + '.mdf';
DECLARE @DBLogName text;
SET @DBLogName = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\\' + @DBName + '.ldf';

CREATE DATABASE [@DBNAME] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = @DBFullName + '_Data', FILENAME = @DBFileName , SIZE = 30720KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = @DBFullName + '_Log', FILENAME = @DBLogName , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Comment: Please see the following for a method on doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-a-variable-for-the-database-name-in-t-sql

Comment: You'll have to use Dynamic SQL for that. Furthermore, I believe `text` isn't allowed as a variable data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL. Also, you need to replace `text` with `nvarchar(max)` otherwise text concatenation won't work.

Here is full script for you:

```
DECLARE @DBNAME sysname;
SET @DBNAME = 'MyDataBase'

DECLARE @DBFullName sysname;
SET @DBFullName = 'MySuperDataBase';

DECLARE @DBFileName nvarchar(max);
SET @DBFileName = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\' + @DBName + '.mdf';
DECLARE @DBLogName nvarchar(max);
SET @DBLogName = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\' + @DBName + '.ldf';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
SET @SQL = N'
  CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBNAME) + ' ON PRIMARY
    (NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@DBFullName + '_Data') + ',
    FILENAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@DBFileName, '''') + ',
    SIZE = 30720KB,
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
    FILEGROWTH = 10%)
   LOG ON (
     NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@DBFullName + '_Log') + ',
     FILENAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@DBLogName, '''') + ',
     SIZE = 2048KB,
     MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
     FILEGROWTH = 10%)'

PRINT @SQL

EXEC (@SQL)
GO
```

Works on my machine! :)

Comment: Ah well :\ this means i'm probably better of with implementing the creation in c#, since my script is a bit longer than only the "Create Database"-statement. It's a giant script, generated by the SQL Management Tool, and i only wanted to add the Name of the DB to control that bit throughout the whole script. If i have to do it with string concatenation on every usage of the DB name, there is little to no improvement ;-) But thank you