# How do I drop a declared variable DB if it exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to drop a declare variable DB name if it already exists. I have the following, but keep on getting a syntax error. *Incorrect syntax near '@DB_NAME'.*

```
USE MASTER  
GO


DECLARE @DB_NAME AS VARCHAR(50) 
SET @DB_NAME = 'TEST' 
DECLARE @DB_PATH AS VARCHAR(200) 
SET @DB_PATH = N'C:\\Clients\\TEST PILOT\\F - Raw Data\\'


IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases where name=@DB_NAME) 
DROP @DB_NAME

CREATE DATABASE @DB_NAME  
ON 
       (NAME = N'@DB_NAME', 
    FILENAME = N'C:\\Clients\\TEST PILOT\\F - Raw Data\\TEST.mdf', 
    SIZE = 1GB , 
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
    FILEGROWTH = 1GB
    )

LOG ON
    (NAME = N'TEST_log', 
     FILENAME = N'C:\\Clients\\TEST PILOT\\F - Raw Data\\TEST.ldf', 
     SIZE = 2024KB , 
     MAXSIZE = 2GB , 
     FILEGROWTH = 10%
    )
GO
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-a-variable-for-the-database-name-in-t-sql

Comment: I think the problem was the incorrect use of backslash. Which @DavidBrabant fixed in the edit. The code in the question should run without problems

Comment: Drop statement is not correct change it to DROP DATABASE [@DB_NAME] and similarly change the create also like CREATE DATABASE [@DB_NAME]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a variable type for Database;

If i'm not wrong you want to delete a database by input in the variable

You can use some dynamic sql to do the same
This is not exact script you can adjust the dynamic sql and get your desired result

```
USE MASTER
GO

DECLARE @DB_NAME AS VARCHAR(50),@ex_sql varchar(max)
SET @DB_NAME = 'TEST'
DECLARE @DB_PATH AS VARCHAR(200)
SET @DB_PATH = 'C:\Clients\TEST PILOT\F - Raw Data\'

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases where name=@DB_NAME)
begin
set @ex_sql='drop database '+@DB_NAME
exec @ex_sql
end 
set @ex_sql=''
set @ex_sql='CREATE DATABASE '+@DB_NAME+
' ON 
(NAME = '''+@DB_NAME+''', 
    FILENAME = ''C:\Clients\TEST PILOT\F - Raw Data\TEST.mdf'', 
    SIZE = 1GB , 
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
    FILEGROWTH = 1GB
    )

LOG ON
    (NAME = ''TEST_log'', 
     FILENAME = ''C:\Clients\TEST PILOT\F - Raw Data\TEST.ldf'', 
     SIZE = 2024KB , 
     MAXSIZE = 2GB , 
     FILEGROWTH = 10%
    )
GO'
exec @ex_sql
```