# SQL using databse name with table name via variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use a variable to fetch the select query using database name, where the database name would be stored in the variable. But i'm not able to achieve this using the below approach. Can one please let me know how to achieve this.

```
DECLARE @PrePublishedDB VARCHAR(100)
SET @PrePublishedDB = 'MyDatabase'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @PrePublishedDB.BaseVehicle
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for the database name in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727788/how-to-use-a-variable-for-the-database-name-in-t-sql)

Comment: @nedmund Is it not possible to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at trying Dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
execute ('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @PrePublishedDB + '.BaseVehicle')
```