# Create database using variable in script failed - invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This question is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727815/6611532)

I want to create a database via a SQL script which checks if the database exists before creation, i.e.

```sql
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(255)
SET @DBNAME = 'TestDB'

DECLARE @CREATE_TEMPLATE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @CREATE_TEMPLATE = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = {DBNAME})
BEGIN
  CREATE DATABASE {DBNAME}
END'

SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@CREATE_TEMPLATE, '{DBNAME}', @DBNAME)
EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT)
```

However, I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid column name 'TestDB'

What's wrong? How can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: You should pass the value in as a *parameter* using `sp_executesql`.  That said, creating databases should be such an unusual activity that automations should not be necessary.

Comment: To debug dynamic SQL you `print` it rather than executing it, then run the result which is now static SQL. At that point your error becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around the DBName.

```
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(255);

SET @DBNAME = 'TestDB';

DECLARE @CREATE_TEMPLATE VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @CREATE_TEMPLATE = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = ''{DBNAME}'')
BEGIN
  CREATE DATABASE {DBNAME}
END';
SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@CREATE_TEMPLATE, '{DBNAME}', @DBNAME);

PRINT (@SQL_SCRIPT);
```